# Normals broke in a custom shader after update from SVF to SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Hello recently in our Forge Autodesk Viewer we swapped from using SVF to using SVF2 by changing the viewer initialize options to

```
{
    env: "MD20ProdUS",
    api: "D3S",
}
```

as was suggested to us by your team. However this caused our custom shader to misplace the normals. We suspect is the issue with different packing since in our shader we use a handy function to unpack the normals values.

```
const float PI = 3.141592;
vec3 DecodeNormal (vec2 enc)
{
    vec2 ang = enc * 2.0 - 1.0;
    vec2 scth = vec2(sin(ang.x * PI), cos(ang.x * PI));
    vec2 scphi = vec2(sqrt(1.0 - ang.y * ang.y), ang.y);
    return vec3(scth.y * scphi.x, scth.x * scphi.x, scphi.y);
}
```

The input to this function is just `normal.xy`

We have a custom shader that shows the normals in a color gradient and when applied to the same model using the same shader we get a different result depending on which Viewer versions we use (SVF or SVF2)
[SVF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuz1s.png)
[SVF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzm1a.png)
I hope the images are visible and you are able to resolve our issue. We had the same issue when we first implemented our custom shader however that normals unpacking function solved it initially that is why we suspect it is the cause of our headaches.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to check with the viewer team for more details on this, but in the meantime:

The SVF2 format can encode normals in a couple of different ways (using two `short`s or `ushort`s, as you can see [here](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/otg/reader.ts#L125-L140)), and it's likely that the viewer keeps the normal data as-is even when sending it to the GPU, meaning that you'll need to modify your WebGL shaders to account for these. I'd suggest that you update your `DecodeNormal` helper function to follow the logic used in the link, and see if the normals come in correctly.

Comment: Well sadly the function you sent in the link uses the same decoding mechanism as one I posted in my question already and it gives incorrect results. Unless there is some other part other than the part you highlighted the fix you suggested didnt work.